# Wicket: Component to reference model from containing Panel

Tags: java, wicket

To illustrate my problem, let's say I have an instance of Thing which has two text properties - 'foo' and 'bar'.

I want to create a Panel to edit instances of Thing.   The panel has two TextField components, one for the 'foo' property and one for the 'bar' property.

I want to be able to call `setDefaultModel()` on my Panel with an instance of `IModel<Thing>` and for the TextField components to reference this model.   How best to achieve this?

Should I override the `Panel.setDefaultModel()` method to also call setModel() on the two TextField components?   Or perhaps create anonymous ReadOnlyModels for the TextField components, overriding the `getObject()` method to retrieve the object from the containing Panel's model?

Neither of these seem very elegant to me, so I was wondering if there's a better way?

Comment: After discussing with colleagues, another option would be to override `Panel.onModelChanged()` to call `setModel()` on the two TextField components.   Any better ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `PropertyModel` for the textFields. Pass the `IModel<Thing>` into the constructor of the `PropertyModel` with `foo` as the property name:

```
add(new TextField("fooFieldId", new PropertyModel(thingModel, "foo")));
```

The `PropertyModel` will figure out that the thingModel is a `Model` and call `getObject().getFoo()` etc.

This assumes the `IModel<Thing>` instance doesn't change, only its underlying object which can be changed calling `setDefaultModelObject`.

Comment: Looks great, but by calling Panel.setModel() will change the model instance, so then the Panel and the PropertyModels will reference different instances of IModel<Thing>.

Comment: Is there a particular reason why the IModel rather than the underlying object needs to change?

Comment: It doesn't need to, but the point is that it can by a user calling `Panel.setModel()` which would break the logic and the user would have no way of knowing without inspecting/debugging the panel itself.

Comment: From my understanding, this is considered a Best Practice so that the values for your text fields will dynamically change. Calling `setDefaultModelObject` changes the underlying object that actually provides the values to your Labels and Form fields.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm just missing the point, but I can't find a `Panel.setModel()` in the JavaDocs of neither [1.4](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.4/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/Panel.html) nor [1.5](http://wicket.apache.org/apidocs/1.5/org/apache/wicket/markup/html/panel/Panel.html). If it's something you implemented maybe you could change it not to replace the model object but to call `model.setObject()` instead?

*Disclaimer*: Can't really check right now, cause there is no wicket at work and my home machine suffered a video card breakdown earlier...

Comment: Ah yes, you are right - I meant `setDefaultModel()`.   In fact I found a related question here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5617983/why-doesnt-my-wicket-panel-rerender-after-changing-the-default-model) which seems to be caused by this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would help?

```
public abstract class AbstractWrapModel<T> extends Object implements IWrapModel<T>
```

Simple base class for IWrapModel objects.

See IComponentAssignedModel or IComponentInheritedModel so that you don't have to have empty methods like detach or setObject() when not used in the wrapper. The detach method calls the wrapped models detach.